# Why doesn't Silverlight work in 64-bit?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, internet-explorer, silverlight

I was using 64-bit IE and Silverlight would not work.  This is ridiculous!  What is the explanation for this?

Comment: what kind of symptoms are you seeing?  any particular error messages?  "would not work" isn't very descriptive; specifics might allow us to give you an explanation.

Comment: @quack It specifically tells me that Silverlight does not support 64-bits

Comment: interesting.  i hadn't realized 64-bit browsing was that far behind the desktop.  i really should install a 64-bit OS one of these days. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash doesn't work in 64-bit either. I think we have to [resign ourselves to a 32-bit browser world for quite a while...](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/01/why-microsoft-isnt-working-on-silverlight-64-bit.ars)

> So why haven't Mozilla and Google bothered to release official 64-bit browsers? For the same reason Microsoft hasn't bothered to produce a 64-bit version of its Silverlight plugin: nobody uses 64-bit browsers.
>
> That might sound like a vicious circle, and it is; if you are using a 64-bit browser, you need to use 64-bit versions of all your plugins, and plugin makers aren't particularly eager to make 64-bit versions until 64-bit browsers start being used with some frequency. There are three key plugins that need to offer 64-bit versions before mainstream users can switch. In order of least important to most important, these are: Silverlight, Java, and Flash.

Comment: From that article: "64-bit browsers are more secure... at least for now." They'll catch up to 32-bit insecurity when the plugin makers start supporting 64-bit :-\

Comment: @Hugh: Exactly, I only run 32bit IE when I have no other option. But the 64bit version works fine for a few admin sites which are locked to IE without using flash/silverlight.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I've been using 64-bit IE as my primary browser for three years.  I have always had to fall back to Firefox/Chrome/32-bit IE for YouTube and now Netflix.  I don't see what the big holdup is.  To me, this presents a clear opportunity for Microsoft to gain an edge Flash by supporting 64-bits!